# Как исправить баг анимации?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть у меня флексбокс, внутри которого 2 блока. (В одном форма, а в другом изображение).

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="form">
            <div class="locationInfo">Главная</div>
            <div class="login">Вход</div>
            <div class="register">Регистрация</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

[image: Вот]

Есть js Код, который срабатывает после нажатия на кнопку "Готово":

```
form.style.filter = "blur(3px)"; //Блюрится до получения результатов от сервера
```

в css для всей формы: `transition: 1s;`
Но когда срабатывает блюр - сначала всё становится черным, а потом блюрится.

[image: 2]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это такое и как с этим бороться?

p.s Чем больше transition - тем дольше черная картинка. (При 10 сек. transition - примерно 1 сек. черная картинка)

Comment: где можно увидеть проблему ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский я проверял в хроме. Щас проверил в других браузерах - всё работает ровно. [Тут](http://placaz.xyz)

Comment: не удаётся получить доступ к сайту

Comment: @МаксимЛенский [Опечатка, извеняюсь](http://playcaz.xyz), но я уже выбрал обходной маршрут проблемы. Решил не блюрить, а затемнять. Но на этом сайте всё осталось как было.